# Canonicalization effect on SERP

Tags: seo, subdomain, canonical-url

I have an established website with 1000's of links and good SERP for many of my pages. My Google Webmasters is now asking to solve an issue which is canonicalization. I prefer `www.example.com` and know how to redirect `http://example.com` to `www.example.com`.

Since my site is already well developed with lot of links from various sources (a lot of them may be to `http://example.com` and not `www.example.com`), will it effect my current rankings?

Answer (score 2):

When you redirect your `example.com` to `www.example.com`, using a `301` redirect, all your existing link-juice will also transfer to the `www` version. But if you're going to redirect it using a `302`, that may block link-juice from flowing to `www` version.

So redirect your site without the `www` to the one with the `www` using a `301` redirect, and also put a canonical tag on it. That will help to prevent your pages from losing any SERP.

Comment: Also specify the preferred domain in GWT and make sure you've verified ownership of both the `www` and non-`www` versions of the domain. Reference: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/44231?hl=en

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Yes I have set the preferred domain in GWT and also using a 301 redirect.

Comment: Then your ranking will not gonna loose @pessi